# Sims 3 Won't Launch from Origin

Tags: macos, the-sims-3, origin

Error message received:

```
The Sims 3 Unable to start game Service initialization failed (0x0175dcbb)
```

I go to my games on Origin and click play on The Sims 3. I have no expansions downloaded onto my computer yet, and am just trying to run the base for now. When I press play, it gives me the registration code and tells me the game will open in an outside launcher. Then, I get the blue screen with the [plumbob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvgqd.jpg) and then the said error message appears.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Origin, and I tried deleting the contents from my The Sims 3 folder, but there are only two things there that continuously reappear when I try to launch the game, always receiving the error message. Please help!

[image]

System Information:

- **OS X version:** 10.8.5
- **Processor:** 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
- **Memory:** 34 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- **Graphics Processor:** Intel HD Graphics 4000 384 MB

Comment: Just to clarify as 'blue screen' can mean multiple things, is this the blue screen to which you are referencing? http://i.imgur.com/ZQkt6Vi.png

Comment: http://imgur.com/0GNloT7

This is my screen shot.

@Lemmings19

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to check all the files Origin installed?
right click on the game and press on "verify game data". Origin will restore destroyed files if it finds any